# I'm trying to return an object, but I'm always getting an empty return

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, object

I'm trying to return an object, but I'm always getting an empty return.
I'm using Node with Sequelize and Mysql database

when I test using the Insomnia i got this: []

when i try to use the api i got this error:[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'iter[Symbol.iterator]')]

**Repository search**

```
import { productModel } from '../../../../database/models/productsModel';
import { Product } from '../../models/Product';
import { IProductsRepository } from '../IProductsRepository';

class ProductsRepository implements IProductsRepository {
  private static INSTANCE: ProductsRepository;

  public static getInstance() {
    if (!ProductsRepository.INSTANCE) {
      ProductsRepository.INSTANCE = new ProductsRepository();
    }

    return ProductsRepository.INSTANCE;
  }

  
  async list(): Promise<Product[]> {
    const product: any = await productModel.findAll();
    console.log(`Os produtos são: `, product);
    return product;
  }
}

export { ProductsRepository };
```

**Use Case**

```
import { Product } from '../../models/Product';
import { IProductsRepository } from '../../repositories/IProductsRepository';

class ListProductsUseCase {
  constructor(private productsRepository: IProductsRepository) {}

  execute(): Promise<Product[]> {
    return this.productsRepository.list();
  }
}

export { ListProductsUseCase };
```

**Controller**

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { ListProductsUseCase } from './ListProductsUseCase';

class ListProductsController {
  constructor(private listproductsUseCase: ListProductsUseCase) {}

  handle(request: Request, response: Response): Response {
    try {
      const products = this.listproductsUseCase.execute();

      return response.status(200).json(products);
    } catch (error: any) {
      return response.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
    }
  }
}

export { ListProductsController };
```

**Index**

```
import { ProductsRepository } from '../../repositories/implementations/ProductRepository';
import { ListProductsController } from './ListProductsController';
import { ListProductsUseCase } from './ListProductsUseCase';

const productsRepository = ProductsRepository.getInstance();
const listProductsUseCase = new ListProductsUseCase(productsRepository);
const listProductsController = new ListProductsController(listProductsUseCase);

export { listProductsController };
```

**Router**

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { listProductsController } from '../module/products/useCases/listProducts';

const productsRoutes = Router();

productsRoutes.get('/product_list', (request, response) => {
  listProductsController.handle(request, response);
});

export { productsRoutes };
```

Comment: I don't see `await` here: `const products = this.listproductsUseCase.execute();`

Comment: wow, I had forgotten, I just put it on and it worked

Comment: Thats why you should use Typescript